# Synchronize Resources with Google Calendar for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

#### Background

I've been setting up a push-notification client in node.js to watch for changes in calendars/events for a user. Setting up `calendar.events.watch` works perfectly, I receive the `sync` notification at myapp.com/notifications as well as all push notifications denoting changes in calendars.

#### Problem

Now, when needing to poll for these updated events, I found it best done by following [Google's Synchronize Resources](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) walkthrough in order to grab a `syncToken` and grab events incrementally. In their java example, it makes sense how they obtain, store, and refresh the `syncToken`'s. However, I cannot seem to find any kind of documentation (or anyone else using them) for node.js.

#### Question

How do you obtain that initial `syncToken` to perform the initial sync on a calendar? Either I've been searching for the wrong keywords or the feature isn't currently supported in the node.js framework, which I would find surprising.

#### Context

Here is my code for what I interpret to be the "full initial sync."
This is a continuation of the Quickstart listed [here.](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs)

```
var google = require('googleapis');

...

function listEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var events = response.items;
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

The `console.log(response);` statement returns...

```
{ kind: 'calendar#events',
  etag: '"**redacted**"',
  summary: 'me@gmail.com',
  updated: '2016-07-19T00:34:55.921Z',
  timeZone: 'America/New_York',
  accessRole: 'owner',
  defaultReminders: [ { method: 'popup', minutes: 30 } ],
  items:
   [ { kind: 'calendar#event',
       etag: '"**redacted**"',
       id: '**redacted**',
       status: 'confirmed',
       htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=**redacted**',
       created: '2016-07-19T00:34:55.000Z',
       updated: '2016-07-19T00:34:55.715Z',
       summary: 'Thing',
       creator: [Object],
       organizer: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       end: [Object],
       iCalUID: '**redacted**@google.com',
       sequence: 0,
       reminders: [Object] } ] }
```

Should that `nextSyncToken` be found in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do an initial full sync (which does not require a syncToken) and as part of that full sync response, you get all the current calendar items and (on the last page if the results are paged) you get a field called `nextSyncToken`.  You then use that `nextSyncToken` value for the next incremental sync.

From the doc on [initial full sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync):

> In the response to the list operation, you will find a field called
>   nextSyncToken representing a sync token. You'll need to store the
>   value of nextSyncToken. If the result set is too large and the
>   response gets paginated, then the nextSyncToken field is present only
>   on the very last page.

You have to store the sync token until you do the next incremental sync and you present that token as part of the incremental sync request.  When you do the next incremental sync, it will then give you a new `syncToken` which you will again store and use for the next incremental sync.

This `syncToken` is how Google knows which change events to send you since your last sync.

Comment: I added some context with code and response. `response.nextSyncToken` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin - Did you see the part about paged results?  You only get the `nextSyncToken` on the last page.  You should have either a `nextPageToken` or a `nextSyncToken` in the response to the full initial sync.

Comment: I did see that. When I ran my initial query, I had a calendar selected with many events. So for simplicity, I did it on one with fewer events (1 event). The `console.log(response)` is above, which has neither a `nextPageToken` nor a `nextSyncToken`.

Comment: Typo. It was updated in the code but not in the explanation.

Comment: Where do you find doc for `google.calendar('v3');` and `calendar.events.list(...)`?  I find doc for `gapi.client.calendar.events.list()` here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js.  You might want to sniff the network and see what http request is actually being sent and received back.

Comment: The code I'm using to test is nearly a carbon copy of the Node.js category listed right under the JavaScript one. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: I'll give you the check for confirming where I should be expecting it. Thanks for the much appreciated help.

Comment: @ChrisMartin - Did you figure out what was causing the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue ended up being, but after a few more iterations the sync token showed up right where you said it would be. I wish I knew what the enabling factor was.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the response does contain 'nextSyncToken' only when the query parameter 'orderBy' is excluded from the request.

All of the unsupported query parameters for using sync tokens are documented at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list under the headline nextSyncToken.